# How to handle cljs-ajax responses?

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript

I am making a request from a clojurescript frontend with cljs-ajax to an API that responds with JSON but it seems like I need to do something to it before I can use it in cljs.

```
(defn all-pieces []
  (GET "/art/pieces" {:handler ajax-success-handler}))
```

When I initialize my app-state I assign the key `:all-pieces (all-pieces)`

When I go to iterate over `:all-pieces` in a component I get the error `Uncaught Error: [object Object] is not ISeqable`.

```
(defn pieces-component []
  [:ul (for [piece (:all-pieces @app-state)]
         [:li (art-piece piece)])])
```

Edited re Pratley:

The code below now results in the state of `all-pieces` being `{}`, see anything wrong?

```
;; -------------------------
;; Remote Data

(defn all-pieces [handler]
  (GET "/art/pieces" {:handler handler}))

;; -------------------------
;; State Management

(def app-state (atom
  {:doc {}
    :saved? false
    :page-state {}
    :all-pieces {}}))


(defn set-pieces-fresh []
  (all-pieces (fn [pcs] swap! app-state assoc :all-pieces pcs)))
```

Comment: try doing a (js/console.log (:all-pieces @app-state)) ... chances are when you are assigning the result, you are are assigning the response object instead of the actual data?

Comment: I'm getting `#object[Object [object Object]]`. It it stuck as a JS object when it should be a cljs map?

Comment: When using js/console.log, it should show as a browsable object in the console, which usually gives some clues about what is in it.

Comment: the result of (all-pieces) is not the response from the call... the request is done asynchronously. You need to assign the response from the callback.

Comment: Ahhhh. I was just replying, let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Problem: `(fn [pcs] swap! app-state assoc :all-pieces pcs)` should be `(fn [pcs] (swap! app-state assoc :all-pieces pcs))`

Comment: What about it is broken?--- Ah, I should have reloaded before sending

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set `:all-peices` to the result of `(all-pieces)`.
The function `ajax-success-handler` should set `:all-peices` instead.
The result of `(all-pieces)` is the result of starting the asynchronous call, not the response. The handler is what gets called when the response arrives.

```
(fn [pcs] swap! app-state assoc :all-pieces pcs)
```

Does not do any swapping, as swap! needs to be in parens... it is just a function that returns pcs. Consider promoting it to a named function so you can test it separately:

```
(def app-state
  (atom {:all-pieces {}}))

(defn pieces-handler [pcs]
  (swap! app-state assoc :all-pieces pcs))

(defn fetch-pieces []
  (GET "/art/pieces" {:handler pieces-handler}))

(fetch-pieces)
```

Comment: So that looks like it should work, and I think it did in terms of fixing the atom assignment. Thanks a ton!