# Fill img with ajax GET request

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to display an image, which i'm getting with an ajax request. I have to do a request, because I need to add headers for authorization. Here is my code to do this:

```
[:img {:src (ajax/GET (str "/api/1.0/image/" 
                       (:company/logo company) "?size=" 100) {
           :headers jwt-authorization-header 
           :format        :json 
           :handler       handler
           :error-handler error-handler})}]
```

I'm returning this:

```
{:status  200
 :headers {"Content-Type" "image/png"}
 :body    (format/as-stream resized-image "png")}
```

So it's not showing the img, I found different things on the internet - but i'm not getting it to work. Has anyone got experience with this?

Comment: Is the second code snippet showing what you get as return value or is this code that you have on the server side to answer the request?

Answer (score 0):

The result of ajax/GET is not the response.
You need to handle the response in your handler function.
See very similar question:
[How to handle cljs-ajax responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906629/how-to-handle-cljs-ajax-responses/35907250#35907250)